# Mac function failure

Tags: macos, cocoa, opengl

I am trying to fix a very interesting crash on the MAC OS X 10.5.

Here is the code:

```
CGLPixelFormatObj pixelFormatObj ;
GLint numPixelFormats ;
CGLPixelFormatAttribute attribs[] =
{
    kCGLPFAFullScreen,
    kCGLPFADisplayMask,
    (CGLPixelFormatAttribute) 0,    /* Display mask bit goes here */
    (CGLPixelFormatAttribute) 0
} ;


if ( display == kCGNullDirectDisplay )
    display = CGMainDisplayID();
attribs[2] = (CGLPixelFormatAttribute) CGDisplayIDToOpenGLDisplayMask(display);


/* Build a full-screen GL context */
CGError error = CGLChoosePixelFormat( attribs, &pixelFormatObj, &numPixelFormats );
if ( pixelFormatObj == NULL )    // No full screen context support
    return NULL;
```

The call to CGLChoosePixelFormat() gives "CGNoError", but "pixelFormatObj" is NULL.

This code supposedly should work as I saw a reference to it online for getting the screen captured (ref. http://cocoadev.com/wiki/ScreenShotCode).

Looking under the debugger in XCode, attribs[2] become "kCGLPFAAllRenderers".

Does anybody have an idea on what conditions this might happen? And how to overcome this?

Comment: "code should work as I saw a reference to it online" - made me giggle, not saying it's not valid, but that's hardly the measure of code quality.

Comment: @Slomojo, all I'm saying that it was working for someone else. At least for the person who posted it. ;-)

Comment: I know what you mean, but it's just not a reliable yardstick, you'd really need to modify the statement "was working for someone else" to read, "was supposedly working for someone else." - If it appeared in a blog or stackexchange example marked as correct, it has a bit more credibility, but on a wiki like that, It's not too unlikely that code has errors. I wish I could be more helpful but I'm pretty green with OpenGL

Comment: @Slomojo: “was allegedly working for somebody else at some point within the last 10 years, probably on an older OS and a different machine, quite possibly on a completely different architecture”

Comment: @PeterHosey +1 for clearly stating what I was intimating.